# Android java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: android

I have use
[Android Cube Demo](https://github.com/justomiguel/AndroidCubeDemo)

In CubeLayout class. I add a interface CubeCompleted

public class CubeLayout extends FrameLayout {

```
private BaseInterpolator mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

public CubeLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CubeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CubeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    View foregroundView = getChildAt(0);
    View backgroundView = getChildAt(1);

    CubeLeftOutAnimation cubeLeftOutAnimation = new CubeLeftOutAnimation();
    cubeLeftOutAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    cubeLeftOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    CubeRightInAnimation cubeRightInAnimation = new CubeRightInAnimation();
    cubeRightInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    cubeRightInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    foregroundView.startAnimation(cubeLeftOutAnimation);
    backgroundView.startAnimation(cubeRightInAnimation);

    cubeRightInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            completed.completedCube();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

}
public interface CubeCompleted {
    public void completedCube();
}

CubeCompleted completed;

}
```

In my Activity. I have Replace a Fragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, mHomeFragment)
            .commit();

}
```

In MyFragment. I overide completedCube

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements CubeLayout.CubeCompleted {

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void completedCube() {
    //  donutProgress();
}
}
```

This is my Bug in Logcat

```
Process: com.seesaa.newsaudiocast, PID: 31189  

                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.view.CubeLayout$CubeCompleted.completedCube()' on a null object reference
at com.seesaa.newsaudiocast.view.CubeLayout$1.onAnimationEnd(CubeLayout.java:56)
at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:374)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Where you have intialized completed object in that class? As I have seen in that code its not initialized. Please intialize and try once do a null check in onAnimationEnd() method

Comment: This is my all code. Please. Help me fix it !!!

Comment: Maybe you should initialize `CubeCompleted completed;`

Comment: What should I do? . Can you give me a code? –

Comment: I would start with learning about what a NullPointerException means. And how to avoid it on your own. It would be much more valuable for you to learn that than someone just handing you working code. Note: It's a Java error. It has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: CubeCompleted completed=this;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: And don't just read the accepted answer. Read at least the top 4-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I think you're trying to implement a callback of some kind, so try this out -

In your `CubeLayout` class, add this -

```
public void setCallBack(CubeCompleted completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}
```

In your fragment, use `findViewById` to find your `CubeLayout`, and attach a listener to it -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    CubeLayout cubelayout = view.findViewById(R.id.cubeLayout);
    cubeLayout.setCallBack(this);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried. It not bug. But , At MyFragment. When I override completedCude. It not working 

@Override
    public void completedCube() {
        Toast.make(....);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `completed` object before calling any methods on it.

Comment: If your CubeLayout is being inflated in HomeFragment, you can use `findViewById` to get an instance of it, then use a setter to set your listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements CubeLayout.CubeCompleted {
 private CubeCompleted cubeCompletedInterface;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    cubeCompletedInterface=getActivity();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void completedCube() {
    //  donutProgress();
}
}
```

/* your animation class remove CubeCompleted completed; */

```
private BaseInterpolator mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

public CubeLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CubeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CubeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    View foregroundView = getChildAt(0);
    View backgroundView = getChildAt(1);

    CubeLeftOutAnimation cubeLeftOutAnimation = new CubeLeftOutAnimation();
    cubeLeftOutAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    cubeLeftOutAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    CubeRightInAnimation cubeRightInAnimation = new CubeRightInAnimation();
    cubeRightInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    cubeRightInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    foregroundView.startAnimation(cubeLeftOutAnimation);
    backgroundView.startAnimation(cubeRightInAnimation);

    cubeRightInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            completed.completedCube();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

}
public interface CubeCompleted {
    public void completedCube();
}



}
```

Comment: You remove CubeCompleted completed;
Why? @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            completed.completedCube();

        }

Comment: can't i initialise from the HomeFragment ??

Comment: In the `CubeLayout` class, there is no object defined called `completed`. How is this call `completed.completedCube();` supposed to work ?